# Why does the packaged Threejs scene display only about 20 frames in the client, but 60 frames in the browser after packaging?

Tags: three.js

I have a Threejs model scene that can run up to 60 frames in the 80 version Chrome browser after packaging, but only about 20 frames in the client. The client is developed based on QT and uses the kernel of Chrome browser version 80.

Why is this happening?